# From sqlite to tableview

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, tableview

***I'm quite new to objective-c so I have a few questions.***

1. How can I get my data from my ***(SQLite)*** database to show on my table view. Actually, I can now SELECT the data from the table, but I don't really know how can I add the name of the items from the database table to my tableview
2. After the first question, how can I click on the tableview cell, that have named from the first question, then move to another controller which shows item's name and description on that view.

***On my loaddata method***, I can already call and select the items from table and show it on NSLog.

Could you guys please show me how to do it, or give me some tutorials or links that I can look and study about what I want further.

***Thank you.***

---

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [self initsql];
        [self loadData];   
        [super viewDidLoad];
        table_menu = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test_1",@"test_2",@"test_3",@"test_4", nil];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return [table_menu count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Item";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [table_menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }

    -(void)loadData {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &workDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name, des FROM WIE_DATA"];


            const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(workDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSString *aname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                    NSString *ades = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                    NSLog(@" Load completed Name = %@ Des = %@",aname,ades);
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }
        sqlite3_close(workDB);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, I think you need such methods.
TableViewController ⇔ DetailDataController

NSObject* Data

```
@property NSInteger dataId;
@pproperty NSString* title;
```

ViewContoller

```
- (NSArray *)arr
{
    FMDatabase* db = [self getConnection];
    [db open];

    FMResultSet*    results = [db executeQuery:SQL_SELECT];
    NSMutableArray* books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    while( [results next] )
    {
        Data* data = [[Book alloc] init];
        data.dataId    = [results intForColumnIndex:0];
        data.title    = [results stringForColumnIndex:1];

        [arr addObject:data];
    }
    [db close];
    return arr;
}

- (Data*)dataAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    return [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //cellIdentifier etc

    Data* data = [self dataAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = data.title;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailDataController* detail = [[DetailDataController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailData" bundle:nil];
    detail.delegate = self;
    detail.data     = [self dataAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer for the queries

1. The data obtained from SQLLite DB can be stored in an NSArray or NSDictionary and the same can be used to load it in UITableView in the method 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' instead of using table_menu.
2. You need to adhere to UITableView delegate methods and in the method 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' check for that particular row and get the details from SQLLite DB. If you are using storyboard you can use [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identified sender:self]; and in method '-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender' handle the same.

   (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
        NSInteger rowSel = indexPath.row;

   ```
    //Get the details from SQLLite DB
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identifier" sender:self];
   ```

   }

   (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
   {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue identifier"]) 
        {
           UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        }
   }

Hope this helps.